# How to merge given Facts in a List in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have 3 facts.

```
myfact1(1,'Hamburg','Berlin', 315).
myfact2(2,'Kiel','Bremen', 175).
myfact3(3,'Essen', 'Oberhausen',50).
```

I want to give the imformation of myfacts as tuple of List. My query of 
`output(List)` should give  a list like:

```
[('Hamburg', 'Berlin', 315),('Kiel','Bremen',175),('Essen','Oberhausen',50)]
```

How can implement the Rule `output/1` in Prolog

Comment: Your facts are poorly defined. Why is each one a different functor? This makes handling the data unnecessarily complex since you'd need to programmatically construct the functors to query the facts. You have `myfact1`, `myfact2`, and `myfact3`, whereas each should just be `myfact`. And unless you really need to index the facts, you don't need the first integer argument, either (necessarily). Then you can use aggregate predicates like `findall((A, B, C), myfact(_, A, B, C), L)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understands it right but I would change the facts to "myfact" in stead of myfact1. In that case:

```
output(List) :-
    findall(myfact(A,B,C,D),myfact(A,B,C,D),List).
```

If you really want to keep myfacts1, ... :

```
output(List) :-
    myfact1(A1,A2,A3,A4),
    myfact2(B1,B2,B3,B4),
    myfact3(C1,C2,C3,C4),

    append([myfact1(A1,A2,A3,A4),myfact2(B1,B2,B3,B4),myfact3(C1,C2,C3,C4)],[],List).
```

There are certainly better ways to work around.

Comment: Your use of `append` is a fairly elaborate or obtuse way to unify the desired list with a variable. You can just say, `List = [myfact1(A1,A2,A3,A4),myfact2(B1,B2,B3,B4),myfact3(C1,C2,C3,C4)]`.

Comment: @Nickelium Sorry its actually just myfact but there are more than 50 Facts so i need to go Rekursiv through the Fact and the first Element of Fact begins with 1 and the last fact  ends in 50 . So i have to go through 50 Facts and append it to my Output List. I need something like x = x+1 to go rekursiv from the first Fact to second one and so on .

Comment: The actual question seems like this : komponist(11, 'Georg Friedrich', 'Händel', 1685, 1759).
komponist(12, 'Serge', 'Prokofiev', 1891, 1953).
komponist(13, 'Claudio', 'Monteverdi', 1567, 1643).
komponist(14, 'Antonin', 'Dvorak', 1841, 1904).
komponist(15, 'Antonio', 'Vivaldi', 1678, 1741).
komponist(16, 'Leopold', 'Mozart', 1719, 1787).
komponist(17, 'Heinrich Ignaz Franz', 'Biber', 1644, 1704).
 collect_komp(Output) should be so implemented   that  it will give output as [('Georg Friedrich', 'Händel', 1685, 1759),('Serge', 'Prokofiev', 1891, 1953),...]).

Comment: In that case, there isn't much difference compare to what I wrote in my answer:

collect_komp(Output) :-
 findall((A,B,C,D),komponist(_,A,B,C,D),Output).